# MySQL Insert via php is showing an error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried to INSERT values into an sql database via php. There is no need to check "database.php" as it works. It shows

> Error: unexpected '$myquery' (T_STRING).

I'm using xampp 3.2.1 as a localhost. NEED HELP FAST.THANKS!!!

```
 <?php 

  require 'database.php';

  $for= $_GET ["for"];
  $approved= $_GET ["approved"];
  $before= $_GET ["before"]

  $myquery="INSERT INTO request('request date', 'request for', 'approved by') VALUES (NOW(),'$for','$approved')";
  $query = mysql_query($myquery);
   ?>
```

Comment: Wrap off `quotes` from `table and column` name instead use backtick.

Comment: and sorry, I forget to tell that I closed the php tag like ?> this.

Comment: You get the error because you forgot a semicolon. Adding the semicolon however won't fix the entire script.

Comment: Sorry to tell Dann it still doesn't work

Comment: mysql is deprecated. You should use mysqli.

Comment: Never use raw data from the client in sql queries, otherwise you risk bobby drop tables -  https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like **Daan** said, you forgot a semicolon. You'll need to make this edit:

```
$before = $_GET["before"];
// note the semicolon at the end of the line
```

Also, you should use back ticks to quote your field names like so:

```
$myquery = "INSERT INTO request(`request date`, `request for`, `approved by`) VALUES (NOW(),'$for','$approved')";
```

One final suggestion, you should move away from using the `mysql_*` functions to using either their `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`.